# Get textbox inside hub section

Tags: c#, xaml

I cant get the textbox inside my hub section

code xaml :

```
      <Hub Header="Chutometro" x:Name="Hub" Margin="0,27,0,-1">
        <HubSection Header="Números" x:Name="HbNumemro">
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                     <TextBlock Text="De" Width="30" Height="30" FontSize="25" Margin="0,0,310,600"></TextBlock>
                     <TextBox x:Name="TxtN1" InputScope="Number" Height="40" MaxLength="15" Margin="0,30,0,0" ></TextBox>
                     <TextBlock Text="Á" Width="30" Height="30" FontSize="25" Margin="0,0,310,430"></TextBlock>
                     <TextBox x:Name="TxtN2" InputScope="Number" Height="40" MaxLength="15" Margin="0,110,0,0" ></TextBox>
                     <Button x:Name="BtN" Tapped="BtN_Tapped" Width="80" Height="80" Content="Okay" Margin="0,120,0,337"></Button>
                     <TextBlock x:Name="TxtBlockResult" FontSize="40" Height="80" Margin="0,280,0,269"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </HubSection>
    <HubSection Header="Letras">

   </HubSection>
</Hub>
```

C# :

```
string txtn1 = TxtN1.Text;
string txtn2 = TxtN2.Text;
```

I'm trying to get the x: name, but cant find

Comment: returns it to me : Error 1 The name 'TxtN1' does not exist in the current context 

TxtN1.Name not work

Answer (score 0):

Because The HubSection contains a DataTemplate is not added directly to the visual tree, in order to get them:

```
  private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textboxes = (sender as Grid).Children.OfType<TextBox>();
        var TxtN1 = textboxes.First(p => p.Name == "TxtN1");
        var TxtN2 = textboxes.First(p => p.Name == "TxtN2");

        string k = "";
    }
```

But I recommend you to use MVVM that will make things easy at long time.